# db2 connect to "DBname" user "UserName" using "Password" is not working while executing script from C# web application

Tags: c#, shell, ssh.net

I am trying to execute shell script from C# web application. Inside that shell script it connects to a database and retrieves data from it. I am able to get desired result while exexuting the script from "**SSH Secure Shell Client**" Tool. But when I try to execute the script from .net application I am not able to connect the database properly.

The line which is try to call is -"**db2 connect to "DBname" user "UserName" using "Password"** "

One more thing I want to know that how will I get to know that database is connected or not?

Please provide me the suggessions for same.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to "execute shell script from C# web application" to "connect to a database and retrieve data"? Does this shell script do something specific with that data that only that shell script can do? This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Actually, I am converting the Desktop application to Web Application. I am not creating any shell script as they are already created. I am just executing those shell scripts from web application. In the script, runtime it retrieves data from table and check whether some part of code needs to be executed or not.